# Product price is zero in cart page when add product 2nd time

Tags: magento, cart, zero

When i added product to cart 1st time, Its working fine. But in 2nd time add product to cart (Same or other product - in both situation), cart item price will be 0. But in checkout page, its showing fine.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
echo 'Product Price: '.$item->getProduct()->getPrice().'<br />';
}
```

When i dubug by above code,I got below answer

```
Price: 
Product Price: 159.00
```

Cart price returns empty. I dunno why. I have checked shopping cart and Catalog Price rules too. There is no promotions rules are exist.

Have any idea, how to fix this issue?

Thank you though!

Comment: Hi there, try to reindexing all and clear cache

Comment: @sagarumaretiya Ya. I have tried! I have been facing this issue from last week.

Comment: @DRAJI did you ever find a solution to this problem...?